# Bipolar coordinates loci

Tags: geometry

Let distances between two points say $ (\pm c,0)$ and $(x,y) $ be $ r_1,r_2.$

Just as constant $ r_1 + r_2$ are ellipses, $ r_1 \cdot r_2$ are Cassinian ovals, etc. what is locus when their  harmonic mean is constant?

I.e., find locus for constant $a$

$$ 1/ r_1 +1/ r_2 =2/a.$$

Their graphed appearance looks like they are Cassinian Ovals but are quite different and not hitherto seen in Lockwood, Mathworld, McTutor &c.,

As pointed out by Imsteffan, these are Cayley's ovals that occur in electrostatics among other sciences. Found in mathcurve.com

[image: Cayley's Ovals]

Comment: Could you include a few example graphs?

Comment: Cayley's ovals, I believe. see for instance http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cayleyovale/cayleyovale.shtml